# merging in Pandas with shared data

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes of the following form:

```
PID    Block    Trial    Response
101    A        1        1
101    A        2        2
102    A        1        1
102    A        2        1

PID    Trial    Fix    Dur
101    1        x      10
101    2        y      12
102    1        z      9
102    2        y      13
```

I need to combine them into a single dataframe that looks like this:

```
PID    Block    Trial    Response    Fix    Dur 
101    A        1        1           x      10
101    A        2        2           y      12
102    A        1        1           z      9
102    A        2        1           y      13
```

I've tried using pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['PID', 'Trial'], how='outer', sort=False). But that just gives something like this:

```
PID    Block    Trial    Response    Fix    Dur 
101    A        1        1           NaN    NaN
101    A        2        2           NaN    NaN
102    A        1        1           NaN    NaN
102    A        2        1           NaN    NaN
101    NaN      1        NaN         x      10
101    NaN      2        NaN         y      12
102    NaN      1        NaN         z      9
102    Nan      2        NaN         y      13
```

I haven't had any luck with pd.join either. I also tried creating a new column with a (PID, Trial) tuple, but using merge on that gave similar results as above. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

You want an inner join:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.read_clipboard()
>>> df2 = pd.read_clipboard()
>>> df1
   PID Block  Trial  Response
0  101     A      1         1
1  101     A      2         2
2  102     A      1         1
3  102     A      2         1
>>> df2
   PID  Trial Fix  Dur
0  101      1   x   10
1  101      2   y   12
2  102      1   z    9
3  102      2   y   13
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['PID', 'Trial'], how='inner', sort=False)
   PID Block  Trial  Response Fix  Dur
0  101     A      1         1   x   10
1  101     A      2         2   y   12
2  102     A      1         1   z    9
3  102     A      2         1   y   13
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried that and it's giving me an empty dataframe. Any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: Are you sure `df1` and `df2` are as you wrote in your question? I replicated the data frames by copying and pasting each one using `read_clipboard`.

Comment: The actual dataframes are very large with many more columns, but they still only have PID and Trial in common. The only think I can think of that is different from in question is that they have different numbers of rows (some subjects have data in one dataframe but not the other). But I would think that the extra rows would just be left out of the merged df.

Comment: Figured it out. The trial columns had different types in each dataframe